# How to display images formula fields in LWC datatable not AURA

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

How to display image formula fields in lightning datatable ?

[image]

Comment: Just create a subclass of the data table and provide custom component implementing this?

Comment: @zaitsman can you give some more details and point towards some examples

Comment: See this https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation specifically `Creating Custom Data Types`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @zaitsman thats helpful.

And also found this example online

https://salesforcecodex.com/2019/10/show-image-in-lightning-web-component-data-table/

Thank you Dhanik Lal Sahni for the detailed example.

Comment: hi, how did you solve this? because, the link you sent is intented for urls, and what you have (and me too) is an html markup... how does that work?

Answer (score 1):

As author have stated, we can use this link to learn how to create custom type:
https://salesforcecodex.com/2019/10/show-image-in-lightning-web-component-data-table/

Afterwards, in the HTML of your custom type, create a lightning-formatted-rich-text which takes the variable string as literal HTML - so it displays correctly:

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-p-top_x-small slds-p-left_x-small">
        <lightning-formatted-rich-text value={value} ></lightning-formatted-rich-text>
    </div> 
</template>
```